# Modify Curl output

Tags: bash

I am saving the information of a curl in a variable. The output is as follows:

```bash
INFOISP=$(curl --silent ipinfo.io | grep -E '"ip"|"hostname"|"region"|"country"|"org"')
```

The output is this:

```
  "ip": "186.152.174.190",
  "hostname": "host190.186-152-174.telecom.net.ar",
  "region": "Santa Fe",
  "country": "AR",
  "org": "AS7303 Telecom Argentina S.A.",
```

I need this:

```
"ip": "186.152.174.190" 
"hostname": "host190.186-152-174.telecom.net.ar" 
"region": "Santa Fe" 
"country": "AR" 
"org": "AS7303 Telecom Argentina S.A."
```

I try with sed using this:

```bash
INFOISP=$(curl --silent ipinfo.io | grep -E '"ip"|"hostname"|"region"|"country"|"org"')
echo ${INFOISP} | sed -e $'s/,/\\\n/g'
```

but the output is not in the same column:

```
  "ip": "186.152.174.190"

  "hostname": "host190.186-152-174.telecom.net.ar" 

  "region": "Santa Fe" 

  "country": "AR" 

  "org": "AS7303 Telecom Argentina S.A."
```

any helps?

Comment: replace your sed with something like `|tr -d ','` or `sed 's/,//g'`

Answer (score 1):

The output of your `curl` command is a well formatted JSON so you could use `jq` for extracting data from it robustly. For what you're trying to do you can use other tools though, for ex. GNU `grep`:

```bash
curl --silent ipinfo.io |
grep -oE '("ip"|"hostname"|"region"|"country"|"org"): "[^"]*"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the filtering within `sed` skipping the need for `grep`

```
$ infoisp=$(curl --silent ipinfo.io | sed -En '/ip|hostname|region|country|org/{s/[^"]*([^,]*).*/\1/p}')
$ echo "$infoisp"
"ip": "186.152.174.190"
"hostname": "host190.186-152-174.telecom.net.ar"
"region": "Santa Fe"
"country": "AR"
"org": "AS7303 Telecom Argentina S.A."
```